# Onclick slider in pure JavaScript - event doesn't changes CSS value

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Im trying to make some kind of slider in pure JavaScript (I can't use jQuery or other frameworks because it is for eBay).

I have function like that:

```
var slider_moves = 0;
var imagecount = document.querySelectorAll(".slides_gsc > img").length;
var slide = document.getElementsByClassName('slider_img_width').offsetWidth;

    function slideLeft(){
        if(slider_moves < imagecount -1){
            document.getElementsByClassName("slides_gsc").style.right +=slide; //for me this is not working
            slider_moves++;
        }
    };
```

Why it is not working? I can't use += or variable to change an CSS value?

Comment: The value for `right` will contain a unit, e.g. `150px`, so you can not treat it as a number.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements, so it doesn't have `offsetWidth` or `style` properties, but each element in the collection has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems. As has been pointed out in other answers, the `document.getElementsByClassName()` function will return a node list, which you need to iterate through. Also the `right` attribute typically contains a unit (unless its value is something like `inherit` or `auto`). Assuming you're working with pixels (since you're assigning a pixel value to `slide`) you could do something like this:

```
 var slide = document.getElementsByClassName('slider_img_width')[0].offsetWidth;
```

and then

```
 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("slides_gsc"); 
 for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
     slider_moves++;
     elements[i].style.right = (slide*slider_moves)+"px";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getElementsByClassName("slides_gsc")
```

will return an array that you will have to loop through, if you know for sure there is only 1 elem with that class use

```
getElementsByClassName("slides_gsc")[0]
```

or use an Id on the element.
if there is more than 1 element use

```
 var elems=document.getElementsByClassName("slides_gsc"); 
 for(var i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
     elems[i].style.right+=slide;
        slider_moves++;
 }
```

Comment: I can't use id, because it's not permited at eBay.

Answer (score 0):

According to [icke's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1389366/icke) answer I done code like that and it's working:

```
var slider_moves = 0;
var imagecount = document.querySelectorAll(".slides_gsc img").length;
var slide = document.getElementsByClassName('slider_img_gsc')[0].offsetWidth;

    function slideLeft(){
        if(slider_moves < imagecount -1){
            slider_moves++;
            document.getElementsByClassName("slides_gsc")[0].style.right = (slide*slider_moves)+"px";
        }
    };
```

Of course it's called by:

```
<div class="right_navigation_gsc navigation_gsc" onclick = "slideRight()"></div>
```

Thanks a lot all of you ;)